# Excel formula results in a array and value error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following equation:

```
=EXP(FORECAST(LN($A4), LN(OFFSET(INDIRECT($B$1 & "!B8"), MATCH($A4, INDIRECT($B$1 & "!A8:A308"), 1) - 1, COLUMN() - COLUMN($B4), 2)), LN(OFFSET(INDIRECT($B$1 & "!a8"), MATCH($A4, INDIRECT($B$1 & "!A8:A308"), 1) - 1, 0, 2))))
```

The calculation is performing linear interpolation in log-log space. In the evaluation of this portion:

```
INDIRECT($B$1 & "!A8:A308"), 1) - 1, COLUMN() - COLUMN($B4), 2)
```

The column difference (`COLUMN() - COLUMN($B4)`) results in an array (e.g., {0}). This causes a value error for the `MATCH()` function. If I run the `INDIRECT(...)` call above, then the column difference doesn't result in an array.  My current solution is wrap the column difference with `LARGE(..., 1)`, which effectively flattens the array.

The question is why does the column difference result in array, and is there a better way to deal with this?

Comment: I know this isnt an answer, but have you considered using a macro or user defined function?

Comment: Unfortunately, macro/functions are not permitted. That isn't a very good answer, but that's the answer.

Comment: This isn't an answer either, but I'm curious:  Does the same issue occur if you use the cell reference in the first `COLUMN()`, (so in cell A1 it's `COLUMN(A1)`)?

Comment: @BrettFromLA Unfortunately, it still fails. See the screen shots linked below.

Comment: @pnuts The function has invalid parameters before it gets there. See the screen shots linked below.

Answer (score 1):

Found it! [Microsoft Office Reference](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/column-function-HP010062409.aspx) says this about the COLUMN function:  "If the reference argument is omitted ... the COLUMN function returns the column numbers of reference as a horizontal array."

That's the explanation. The solution, then, is to use `COLUMN(A1)` instead of `COLUMN()`.

Comment: @arkottke If this answer helps you, I'd appreciate an upvote on it. Thanks!

Comment: That looks really promising. I went ahead and made the change, but it still fails. [Here](http://i.imgur.com/DLW0y6m.png) is the debug process on the equation. Notice that `COLUMN(B4)` still returns {2}, and {2} - {2} = {0}.

Comment: Wow! I thought that would fix it. Bummer. :-/

Comment: From the documentation, it sounds like it should fix the problem. I have been disappointed by MS documentation in the past, and this is another example.

Comment: Now I'm researching what a "horizontal array formula" is, because the Microsoft Office Reference mentions that.

Comment: Everything I found says your formula should work. I'd say it's an Excel bug.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I upvoted your answer since, I think technically it was correct, but I agree I think it is a bug.